# Menu button (position: fixed) visibility problem

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with menu button (position: fixed) color.
I want to make button text color oposit to background, but can't find the solution.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #0b1433;
}
.content:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 24px;
  right: 1vw;
  top: 40%;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  border-right: 6px double #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="menu">
    <span>MENU</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to reverse the colours?

Comment: Yes, i think it would be the best solution for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reverse the colours of the text depending on the background colour, use `filter: invert(1);` and `mix-blend-mode: difference;` in the `.menu` class.
Example:

```
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 24px;
  right: 1vw;
  top: 40%;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  border-right: 6px double #000;
  filter: invert(1);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

Full code:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="menu">
    <span>MENU</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #0b1433;
}
.content:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 24px;
  right: 1vw;
  top: 40%;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  border-right: 6px double #000;
  filter: invert(1);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/ZEGNBWY

Comment: Thank you, it helps me. I had a problem because I haven't specify background-color for white blocks. With default background it's doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Change your styling for `.menu` to this.

```css
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 24px;
  right: 1vw;
  top: 40%;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  border-right: 6px double #000;

  mix-blend-mode: difference; /* This will change the color */
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);  /* Needs to be white if you want black text */
}
```

The last two properties will give you the desired effect.

It will change the color of your menu into the opposite color of the background that's underneath it.